# Ruby interpolation in class name

Tags: ruby, interpolation

I have the following line:

```
<div class="fact-circle--<%= #{i} %>" data-number="20">
```

I thought it was possible to interpolate ruby variables like that?

It's choking on the "<" of the opening ERB tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should consider [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that address your questions. It's both helpful and polite.

Comment: Yes, I of course accept answers but when I get a popup stating I have to wait another 9 minutes to accept an answer then I have to wait another 9 minutes! Please be patient. I do try to be helpful and polite when other people have spent their time helping me.

Comment: FWIW, it's not a matter of patience. I simply noticed that you had commented on multiple answers, indicating that they were helpful. In my experience on SO, this is often a prelude to the question being abandoned by the OP without an answer being accepted. My comment wasn't intended as an indictment against _you specifically_, but rather an indictment against that general behavior.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for reminding me. I would have come back and marked as an answer but it was due to timing that I couldn't initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to interpolate from within your ERB tags. Try the following instead:

```
<div class="fact-circle--<%= i %>" data-number="20">
```

The alternative (which includes interpolation) would be as follows:

```
<div class='<%= "fact-circle--#{i}" %>' data-number="20">
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `#{i}`, you should place valid Ruby code inside of erb tags. #{} is used for interpolation in Ruby string, not erb tags. So your code should probably be:

```
<%= div class="fact-circle--<%= i %>" data-number="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string interpolation, you have to put your interpolation in a string :-)

```
<div class="fact-circle--<%= "#{i}" %>" data-number="20">
```

As it was, you had a Ruby comment inside the erb output tags.

But as others have pointed out, there's no need to use interpolation for this, as you're not doing anything other than outputting the value of `i`, so the accepted answer is probably better for what you want to do.